# How to select the latest record of each different value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Based on this table:

[image]

How can I return the latest record of each different vehicle ( assuming I know the values, but if there is a solution that assumes I don't know them it would be better) so let's say for this particular database it would return those in the red box (column id is A.I.):

[image]

i have tried with MAX (id) but for some reason it returns null

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like `SELECT vehivle FROM TableName WHERE date=(SELECT max(date) FROM TableName)`

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select max id from the different value that you are asking. This example works if your id is auto increment and the latest the id inserted the bigger the date.
For example:

```
create table `car` (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
`date` varchar(40) default null,
staff varchar(50) default null,
staffindex int(3) default null,
vehicle varchar(50) default null,
vehicleindex int(3) default null,
fuel varchar(30) default null,
km varchar(30) default null,
comments varchar(255) default null,
Primary key id(`id`) );

insert into  car values (1,"26/08/2021","Christos","0","ITY-2683","2","50","128.315",""), (2,"27/08/2021","Sotiris","1","IOY-3949","3","65","322.522","car needs cleaning"), (3,"26/08/2021","Vaggelis","0","ITY-2682","2","50","128.315",""),(4,"26/08/2021","Teo","1","YTI-7963","3","65","322.522","car needs cleaning"),(5,"26/08/2021","Christos","0","ITY-2683","2","50","128.315",""), (6,"27/08/2021","Sotiris","1","IOY-3949","3","65","322.522","car needs cleaning"), (7,"26/08/2021","Vaggelis","0","ITY-2682","2","50","128.315",""),(8,"26/08/2021","Teo","1","YTI-7963","3","65","322.522","car needs cleaning");

select * from car;
```

[image]

And for your solution you can use:

```
 select * from car where id in (select max(id) from car group by staff) order by id desc;
```

[image]

I am using MariaDB, the same is for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the max date might help you to solve your problem.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Dates IN (SELECT max(Dates) FROM table);
```

Comment: You need a _correlated_ subquery - to get the vehicle's lates date.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

`Select Max(Dates) MaxDate, vehicle  From Table1 Group by vehicle`

> From the above query you will get maxDate for each vehicle, if this is
> not your answer then please provide more information what and how you
> want to display your records.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I return the latest record of each different vehicle

One method is a correlated subquery.  Assuming by latest you mean by `date`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.vehicle = t.vehicle);
```

With an index on `(vehicle, date)`, this is probably the most performant solution.

MySQL also lets you use `in` with tuples:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.vehicle, t.date) in (select t2.vehicle, max(t2.date)
                              from t t2
                              group by t2.vehicle
                             );
```